# Vertically center text on jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Is it possible to vertically center the text on the autocomplete options I get?

As u can see the text it is on the top of the box and i apparently cannot move it vertically:

https://jsfiddle.net/tL2f6hoa/1/

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    background:red;
    height:3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting a height for the object you can set a padding instead to get the same effect.

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    background:red;
    padding: 10px 3px;
}
```

Hope it Helps. Cheers!